# Scala generic: type mismatch

Tags: scala, collections

In the purpose of learning, I would like to understand how "::" class is working.
So I decided to create my own but instead of calling it "::" I want to call it ":++:"

From [List.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L356) source code, the [University of Helsinki](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/wikla/OTS/Sisalto/examples/html/ch22.html) and Programming In Scala 2nd edition (Chapter 22) I should write:

```
abstract class List[+A] {
    def isEmpty: Boolean
    def head: A
    def tail: List[A]
}

final case class :++:[A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A] {
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
}
```

I can create "::" objects

> new ::(1, List(2))

But I can't create my ":++:" objects:

```
new :++:(1, List(2))
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
found   : List[Int]
required: List[?]
            new :++:(1, List(2))
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annotating the `:++:` type parameter gives you a hint:

```
scala> new :++:[Int](1, List(2))
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.scala.collection.immutable.List[Int]
 required: List(in object $iw)[Int]
              new :++:[Int](1, List(2))
                                   ^
```

The `:++:` constructor expects one of your custom `List[A]` instances, but you give it a normal Scala `List(1)`.

But you currently have no way to create an instance of your list (other than having a `null` tail). If you add an equivalent of `Nil`, then you are all good:

```
case object Empty extends List[Nothing] { 
  def head = ???
  def isEmpty = true
  def tail = ???
}
```

And then you can create a `:++:`:

```
scala> val a = new :++:[Int](1, Empty)
a: :++:[Int] = :++:(1,Empty)

scala> val b = new :++:(2, a)
b: :++:[Int] = :++:(2,:++:(1,Empty))
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [gourlaysama's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20825352/1180426) which explains why your definition is shadowed by the built-in `List`, I'd like to drop a few hints.

1. Per answer above, you should also add the `Empty` or `CNil` case object for the 'empty' list.
2. If you check the sources again, you'll find 'cons' method in the built-in `List`, similar to one below:

---

```
sealed abstract class ConsList[+A] {
    (...)
    def :++:[B >: A](x : B) : ConsList[B] = new :++:(x, this)
}
```

---

It allows you to create the list using infix notation:

```
val b = 2 :++: 4 :++: 7 :++: CNil
```

And finally, you can create a companion object for easier list creation:

```
object ConsList {
  def apply[A](xs : A*) = {
    xs.foldRight(CNil : ConsList[A])((el, l) => el :++: l)
  }
}
```

Which means that you can now create `val c = ConsList(2, 4, 7)` which will be equivalent to `b` above, and also equivalent to `:++:(2, :++:(4, :++:(7, CNil)))`